# stepUp and stepDown don't work in Edge and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

stepUp and stepDown don't work in Edge and IE.

```
<span class="minusIcon" onclick="document.getElementById('quantity').stepDown(1)"">-</span>
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" disabled="disabled" max="10" id="quantity" class="quantity" value="1" />
<span class="plusIcon" onclick="document.getElementById('quantity').stepUp(1)">+</span>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngcputf5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, they are not supported: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp

I would create an adjustQty function and pass the modifier.

```
<script>
function adjustQty(modifier) {
    document.getElementById('quantity').value += modifier;
}
<script>


... onclick="adjustQty(1)" ...
```

You could also add stepUp / stepDown functions to the input object **prototype**, but that is far more complicated.

Comment: As always Microsoft consider is not important to keep up. Classic ! The function is very slim, you have to consider checking for lower limit and do the substracting too. Get's a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

As @noah-b pointed out, these methods are not supported for `type="number"`. However, they *are* supported for `type="range"`. Knowing this, you can cheat your way towards having native `stepUp` and `stepDown` functionality:

```
const numberField = document.getElementById('quantity');

numberField.type = "range";
try {
    // We have to use "try" here because when overstepping the min or max value, this method will throw an error, leaving our input field in the "range" type
    numberField.stepDown();
} finally {
    // IE11 discards the value when changing back to number so we have to reset it manually.
    const newValue = numberField.value;

    numberField.type = "number";
    numberField.value = newValue;
}
```